# How to add header to a specific column in linux

Tags: linux, header

I have a file with x columns and i would like to add header to nth column. For instance i have a sample tab-delimited file as shown below:

```
col1 col2    col4
1     2    3   4
3     4    4   5
```

I would like to add header to column3. the output looks like:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
1     2    3   4
3     4    4   5
```

Could anyone suggest to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a change to record number 1, it's as simple as:

```
awk 'NR==1{print $1" "$2" col3 "$3;next}{print}' inputfile
```

On that first line, it will insert the extra column. All others will be printed as is.

Comment: I am trying it on the last column i.e 15th column in my original data file: awk 'NF==15{print $0, "GC";next}{print}' input. It prints GC in all rows, which should print only the header without changing the remaining rows.

Comment: @user1779730, then each line probably has 15 columns in it, despite your earlier assertion :-) I've updated the answer with a better option.